# if logic in posts_where not working wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

My if ( $filter == 'on' ) in the ugrestriction_filter function seems to not be working in this code when viewing a post. I'm executing this from functions.php It does work when viewing a page. How can I make this work?

Here's my code:

```
// Join metadata
function ugrestriction_join($join) {
global $wp_query, $wpdb;

    $join .= "LEFT JOIN ($wpdb->postmeta) ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) ";


return $join;
}

add_filter('posts_join', 'ugrestriction_join');


// Prevent duplicates

function ugrestriction_distinct( $where ) {
global $wpdb;

    return "DISTINCT";

return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'ugrestriction_distinct' );


    // Filter posts
    function ugrestriction_filter( $where, $wp_query )
    {
        global $wpdb, $post, $current_user, $wp_query;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;
        $page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
        $post_id = $post->ID;

        $meta_key1    = '_ugrestriction';
        $meta_key1_value  = 'on';

        $postids=$wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
          "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value = 'on'", "_ugrestriction"
        ) ); 


        //$postids = array("70", "1", "2", "3");

        if (in_array($post_id, $postids)) {
          $filter = 'on';
        } elseif (in_array($page_id, $postids)) {
          $filter = 'on';
        } 


        if ( $filter == 'on') {
          $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_ugrestriction' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'on' AND " .  $wpdb->posts . " .post_author =". $user_id .")";
        }

            return $where;
    }

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'ugrestriction_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> Certain functions which retrieve posts do not run filters, so the
>   posts_where filter functions you attach will not modify the query. To
>   overcome this, set suppress_filters to false in the argument array
>   passed to the function

[Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where#Note)

Have you tried this?

Comment: Just tried adding that below add_filter, as shown in the example. This didn't do anything for me, same results. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Second thing that comes to my mind is trying out the priority. In your code, where you apply the filter, there's the integer 10 as 3rd parameter. Have you tried to modify this?

Comment: I haven't, what value would you suggest?

Comment: I'd suggest to try it with 1. I've also looked at the hook where it's fired, if "suppress_filters" is false (which it is by default), your filter should work. I don't know what plugins you have installed, maybe you need to grep over the other plugins if there is any causing the poblem. You can try a simple die(); too, to see, if your function is called at all.